# Comparing $n!$ and $(\frac n3)^n$

Tags: inequality, factorial

> Compare which of $n!$ and $\left(\dfrac n3\right)^n$ will stay larger for $n$ large enough?

The answer is undoubtedly $n!>\left(\dfrac n3\right)^n$ and I'm trying to prove this.

My first approach was to prove that $$n+1>\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{3n^n}\tag{1}$$ for $n$ large enough. This could establish the inductive relationship $$n!>\left(\dfrac n3\right)^n\implies(n+1)!>\left(\dfrac{n+1}3\right)^{n+1}$$thus solve the problem. (Geogebra graph told me this is true) However I found $(1)$ hard to prove.

---

My second approach was the Stirling formula$$n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n.$$So$$n!>\left(\dfrac n3\right)^n\Leftrightarrow\sqrt[2n~~~]{2\pi n}>\frac e3.$$
I again failed to complete the proof. I'm now out of ideas so I need help.

Comment: The second approach has also arrived at a point where the inequality is obviously correct. $\sqrt[2n~~~]{2\pi n}>1>\frac e3$. (I was just considering high leveled properties and forgot this)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearranging (1) yields
$$3 > \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$$
The right-hand side converges to $e$ as $n \to \infty$.