# Compare $n!$ and $(\log n)^n$

Tags: asymptotics

I think that $n!$ grows fast than $(\log n)^n$ but how do you show that?

I'm doing a practice exam right now and I have to compare functions. Is this correct?

$28 <\log n^{2020} < 5n^{3/7} < 2^{n^{1/2}} < (\log n)^{n/2} < n! < n^n$

I know how to show everything apart from $(\log n)^{n/2} < n!$.

Comment: It's not a real exam, I'm just practicing old exams for my real exam on monday

Comment: We didn't have that in this course

Comment: Hint:$$\log n!=\sum_{k=1}^n\log k\sim\int^n\log xdx\sim n\log n.$$Take logarithms, then use $\log\log n\in o(\log n)$.

Comment: $\log$ is so weak. This could solve it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4601272/comparing-n-and-frac-n3n

Comment: Thanks, I got it!